# Why does Nginx go to the incorrect url when there is no slash at the end of the url?

Tags: nginx, configuration, routes

This works:
https://www.example.com/news/language/url-to-news-content/

This goes to backend. subdomain instead of the center domain:
https://www.example.com/news/language/url-to-news-content

```
location ^~ /news/ {
rewrite ^/news(/.*)$ $1 break;
proxy_pass      http://backend.example.com/;
proxy_set_header Host backend.example.com;
sub_filter "http://backend.example.com/" "https://www.example.com/news/";
sub_filter "https://backend.example.com/" "https://www.example.com/news/";
sub_filter "http:\/\/backend.example.com\/" "https:\/\/www.example.com\/news\/";
sub_filter_once off;
break;
}
```

Comment: Try: `curl -I https://www.example.com/news/language/url-to-news-content` to find out what is happening.

Comment: @RichardSmith well what I then see happening is that urls without / on the end don't get rerouted but go to backend.example.com instead